# Export mesh from Blender With UV and Bones

Tags: modeling, export, hair

So I have a model which has its hair meshes with its own bones and UV. My final goal  is to generate a NIF file  of that hair from blender with bones and UV but I am not able to do that. How can I export a NIF of that hair from blender so that it has its own bone in the NIF file and also it has its UV so that I can use the textures directly without needing to edit the UV?